# How to increase stack size of threads used by `cargo test`?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

I have a program that uses a large amount of stack. I use Linux, and so have already set the stack size limit via `ulimit -s 1048576`.

Running `cargo test -- --test-threads 1` works as expected, but when I use more than one thread, e.g. `cargo test -- --test-threads 2`, I get `fatal runtime error: stack overflow`. I believe this is because the Rust thread default stack size, used when running tests, is too small.

How do I increase this stack size when running `cargo test`?

Answer (score 5):

[Found it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/#stack-size): `RUST_MIN_STACK`, as in `RUST_MIN_STACK=104857600 cargo test`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stacker](https://crates.io/crates/stacker) to increase the size of the stack dynamically.